# Embedded bitmap files and assembly size

Tags: wpf, resource-files

I have several large embedded bitmap files in my resource project. The compiled exe is 13 megs. When I remove those bitmap files, it reduces to 6 megs.

I am trying to improve performance of the application. It is a WPF desktop application. Would it be better to load the images from disk rather than embed them in the exe? Should I convert them to png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should not embedded image into your compiled .exe, it's just the resource, then should load them from disk.

Generally, convert image files into .png is preferable.

Hope this help.